# $this->getQuote()->setData(); not working in saveBilling() in Onepage checkout Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, customer

I am trying to set a custom attribute for customer in `saveBilling()` method of `Onepage.php` Path for Onepage.php is

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php
```

In `saveBilling()` i have written below code

```
$this->getQuote()->setData("customer_dri_license","22");
```

as you can see i am trying to set value `22` for `customer_dri_license`

I want to retrieve this value in `saveOrder()`, for that i have written below line of code

```
$this->getQuote()->getData("customer_dri_license")
```

but i am not receiving value `'22'` as set in `saveBilling()`

Please let me know if i'm missing something.

Comment: The problem is, that your value is not saved. So if you try to get this value in another request, the value is gone. But use the session as Marina is recommending.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to use the checkout session object to set the data you want to use in `saveOrder()`. The data you are setting in the quote object will be lost from one call to another.

In the `saveBilling` method you could use:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setData('customer_dri_license'`, '22');
```

And in the `saveOrder` method you can use:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getData('customer_dri_license');
```